# SU tags: recommend better tag for DSL (the linux distribution)

Tags: discussion, tags

Someone posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/120912/defualt-root-pass) on Damn Small Linux and tagged it **[dsl]**.  Once I figured out *why*, I checked the [other **[dsl]** questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dsl) and found [another](https://superuser.com/questions/111549/few-question-about-linux-closed).

Since there were only two, I retagged manually.  There doesn't seem to be a distribution-specific tag for Damn Small Linux, so I had to create one (or remove the tag).  My gut inclination was to tag them with **[damn-small-linux]**, which is correct, but ... well, impolite.  I ended up creating the tag [**[dsl-linux]**](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dsl-linux) instead.

Considering the existing [**[language-that-shall-not-be-named]**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/brainfuck) tag on SO, should we throw propriety to the wind, and go ahead and use the full **[damn-small-linux]**?

Comment: i should point out that i'm asking because it's not a distro i'm overly familiar with.  if the distro's community uses "DSLinux" to refer to it, then **[dslinux]** is a more appropriate tag than the one i settled on.

Answer (score 11):

Damn is at best a mild profanity.

At worse, you're being redundant with DSL-Linux.

If it's called Damn Small Linux, tag it **[damn-small-linux]** and move on.

Answer (score 3):

That is, after all, the name of the distro.